# Highlight syntax by regex in ICSharpCode TextEditor, or highlight without .xshd file?

Tags: .net, text-editor, icsharpcode

I would like to highlight interpolation modes in G-code with distinct colors. When a G0 or G00 is found, the code will be a certain color. The color will change upon (G1 or G01) or (G2 or G02), etc.

I would need to enforce conditions to make this work, either by regex or parsing.

It appears that there is no built-in method for highlighting by regex. Is that correct? If so, what would be the most practical way to approach this problem using ICSharpCode.TextEditor?

Comment: Either you follow the highlighting approach provided by this component, or you hack it to add the one you want. I am not sure what are you asking for here.

Comment: I was hoping someone would say that my presumption was incorrect, or that it's an easy hack if I just modify function x. I'm way too ignorant to pull this off today. Maybe someday...